# Android layout - Hierarchical definition

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very new to Android development, so I may be asking something really stupid and the answer might simply be 'no'. But can't find a sound answer anywhere.

I know that you can include some "snippets" in an Android layout with the tags `include` or `merge`, but what I'm really looking for is if it is possible to do that the other way around.

Is it possible to define Android layout in a MVC style? That is, definining a base layout and then customize inner parts of it, a bit like you do in a Java MVC web app?

Required compatibility at least with KitKat (Jelly Bean would be better).

**EDIT - Pseudo code requested**

Actually, I can't imagine how a code could look like in Android to do that.

I try to describe it graphically.

What I'm able to do so far is including or merging:

```
LAYOUT <-- this is the layout specific for my activity
|     -----------
|-----| SNIPPET |  <-- generic snippets which can be reused
      -----------
```

which means that my layout actively includes a snippet (for instance, a progress bar, or the typical progress circle)

What I'd like to be able to achieve is the opposite way:

```
---------------
| ROOT LAYOUT |  <-- generic layout defined for ALL activities
---------------
|
|---- CUSTOMIZATION  <-- this is defined for each specific activity.
```

A classic example in web development, which I'm more used to, is the definition once and for header and footer in a basic layout file. Then each web page (or JSP(X)) will redefine the content of the page *deriving* from the root layout, thus inheriting (a bit in OOP flavour) the common parts defined in the root layout.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Can you show some (pseudo) code of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @nhaarman hi, I've tried to make it clearer

Comment: Something like... `Root Layout = Activity` and `Customization = Fragment`?

Comment: @DerGol...lum actually I see it more like `Root Layout = collection of reusable Fragments` and `Customization = Activity`

Comment: You could make a base Fragment and inherit (extend it) in new fragments. Sort of an Interface.

Comment: @DerGol...lum actually, Fragments look like what I'm trying to do, reading the documentation. Will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

You seem to look for `<include>` tag. See docs on this subject here: [Re-using Layouts with `<include/>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). You can also consider using `Fragments` yet, it is not an equivalent to `<include>` and sometimes may be an overkill for what you want to acheive.

Comment: actually, Fragments look like what I'm trying to do, reading the documentation. Will give it a try